# how to remove lines based on a number

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a data like this

```
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
305
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
534
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
544
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
393
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
559
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
359
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
189
>sp|Q14671|PUM1_HUMAN Pumilio homolog 1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUM1 PE=1 SV=3
1186
```

each line comes with a number under them, I want to identify those ones that have a lower number than 350 and remove the lines from it

I want to come to an output like this

```
P13674 534
Q7Z4N8 544
P04637 393
Q9UHX1 559
Q06416 359
Q14671 1186
```

I can try to grab the strings in between || but I cannot delete the

```
awk -F '[| ]' '/^>/ { print $3}' < data.txt
```

Comment: You'll find it easier to use awk if you can think about your problems in terms of what you want to **print** rather than what you want to delete since awks default operation, just like grep, is to print something when a condition is true.

Comment: @Ed Morton my problem is how to select the string from the data

Comment: I already posted an answer, I'm just commenting that you should avoid thinking about problems in terms of what you want to remove/delete and think about them in terms of what you want to select/print and you'll find the logic much easier to grasp and the resultant code usually easier to understand and enhance later. Focus on positives, not negatives, that's all.

Comment: @Ed Morton thanks a lot for teaching me something today ! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'|' '/^>/{v=$2; next} $0>=350{print v, $0}' file
P13674 534
Q7Z4N8 544
P04637 393
Q9UHX1 559
Q06416 359
Q14671 1186
```

Comment: I have to wait then accept your answer in 6 minutes , thanks

Comment: You should always wait a few hours after posting a question to see what answers you get. If you just accept the first answer you get then you discourage others from posting answers and there may be better answers out there. A program that produces the output you expect from some sample input you post is the starting point to identifying a solution, not the end point.

Answer (score 1):

One more awk with the help of paste command

```
paste - - < learner.txt  | awk -F"[|\t]" ' $NF>350 { print $2,$NF } '
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat learner.txt
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
305
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
534
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
544
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
393
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
559
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
359
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
189
>sp|Q14671|PUM1_HUMAN Pumilio homolog 1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUM1 PE=1 SV=3
1186

$ paste - - < learner.txt  | awk -F"[|\t]" ' $NF>350 { print $2,$NF } '
P13674 534
Q7Z4N8 544
P04637 393
Q9UHX1 559
Q06416 359
Q14671 1186

$
```

Comment: liked your solution, could you also show how you selected the regular expression ?

Comment: ````paste - - <learner.txt```` will join every 2 lines from the learner.txt file. The lines will be joined by a  tab ````\t````. So the paste output will be one line for every 2 lines in the input.. then the remaining stuff is awk

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl also

```
perl -F"\|" -lane ' /^(\d+)/ and $1>350 and print $p,"\t",$1; $p=$F[1] '
```

with given inputs

```
$ cat learner.txt
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
305
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
534
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
544
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
393
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
559
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
359
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
189
>sp|Q14671|PUM1_HUMAN Pumilio homolog 1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUM1 PE=1 SV=3
1186

$ perl -F"\|" -lane ' /^(\d+)/ and $1>350 and print $p,"\t",$1; $p=$F[1] ' learner.txt
P13674  534
Q7Z4N8  544
P04637  393
Q9UHX1  559
Q06416  359
Q14671  1186

$
```

Comment: liked your solution, could you also show how you selected the regular expression ?

Comment: ````/^(\d+)/```` will match only when the line starts with a number which means the second line..and $1 will have the matched value.. $p=$F[1] will match the Q96A73